# Inserting multiple elements into another element in PrototypeJS?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In PrototypeJS, is there a more efficient way to insert multiple Element objects into an element? Here is the code I have now:

```
var calendar_elem = new Element('div', {
    'id': 'my_calendar'
}).insert({
    bottom: title_elem   // assume these are all Element objects
}).insert({
    bottom: days_of_week_elem
}).insert({
    bottom: month_calendar_elem
}).insert({
    bottom: footer_elem
});
```

Can the `bottom` index contain an array, or must it contain only one Element/string of HTML? Would it be more efficient to get the HTML of each element being `insert`ed, concatenate them, and pass that into `bottom` instead? Thanks!

Comment: By "efficient" do you mean (say) speed at runtime, or in terms of code size? If the former, it's very unlikely to actually matter in the real world.

Comment: Speed at runtime. And I know, but I always strive for efficiency and least load/run time possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dom manipulations are expensive because they cause page repaint/reflow after each change. It's best to build up your HTML as a string (or in memory) and insert them into the DOM all in one go.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. Based on this, I am using strings of HTML instead of Element objects. Just makes more sense now that I think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I thought of a few minutes after posting the question:

```
[title_elem, days_of_week_elem, ...].each(function(obj)
{
    calendar_elem.insert({
        bottom: obj
    });
});
```

But I was hoping for a method that was built into PrototypeJS for doing this. If this is the only way of making the code more efficient, please let me know. Thanks.